# SBT, include entire external directory (with the dir itself) in jar built

Tags: scala, build, sbt

I need to include entire `static` directory from external location in my SBT-generated JAR file (with optional folder renaming).

Adding it's path to `unmanagedResourceDirectories` adds **its content** only, not the entire directory which results in `static` content in the JAR root. I was playing with mappings of various sorts but with no luck.

Does anyone had similar use-case and could point me to the right direction on how to do that?

I can't modify the process that generates the `static` dir and can't use it's parent as it has other files/dirs I don't want inside.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I sorted it out with a little hint I got on sbt's gitter channel. So `mappings` is what I needed:

```
mappings in (Compile, packageBin) := {
  val statics = contentOf(baseDirectory.value / "static").map {
    case (file, dest) => file -> s"webapp/$dest"
  }
  (mappings in (Compile, packageBin)).value ++ statics
}
```

This will take all the content from `static` directory and place it in the `webapp` directory of the resulting JAR file