# Can a resource directory be mapped to an alternate location in the jar with SBT?

Tags: sbt

Is it possible to include a resource directory, such that it's path is prefixed when added to the jar created by `sbt package` (v1.1.6)?

---

For context, the mapping I wish to achieve is:

`./src/main/python/* -> jar:/resources/*`

I currently have the following line in `build.sbt`:

```
Compile / unmanagedResourceDirectories ++= Seq(
  baseDirectory.value / "src" / "main" / "python"
),
```

Which results in the mapping:

`./src/main/python/* -> jar:/*`

---

*As a caveat, I am aware that I could nest a `resources` directory inside the `python` directory to achieve this, however this question is specifically trying to avoid doing that if at all possible, in the interests of making the project structure as friendly as possible to developers with a primary background in Python rather than Java or Scala.*

Comment: I think this is the same as this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51614886/736957. No answer there yet, just telling you so that you can watch it too.

Comment: You're right, while not exactly what I needed, the answer posted there now was enough to get me where I needed, thanks for the tip off.